# Joining two tables on multiple values of the joining column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck in situation where I am unable to make any progress.
The requirement is below.

I have two tables one is ContentTag

```
   Id   ContentId   TagId
   1        48       3
   2        48       4
   3        48       5
   4        48       6
   5        47       7
   6        47       8
   9        47       1
   10       47       2
```

This contains the linking between Content table and tag table

and there is foldettag table which contains the linking between folder table and tag table

```
Id      FolderId    TagId   
2           2         3     
3           2         4     
4           2         5     
5           2         6     
6           4         3     
7           5         1     
8           5         2     
9           5         3     
10          10        1
```

the folder will contain only those contents which are linked to all the tags which are liked to the folder.

Note: I need the result whihc contains the link of those contentId and FolderId which are linked to exactly same tags.

for example it will contain the following result

```
ContentId     FolderId
   48            2
```

Can someone plz suggest to me some approach which I should follow to proceed with this?

I am trying to find a solution for the past few hours but unable to find any solution
Thank you

Comment: How do you know which tags are liked?  What results do you want. The actual question is unclear.

Comment: HI @GordonLinoff, Tags are linked to content and folders are also linked to tags, So I need to link content to the folder and filter it to have only those contents which are linked to all the tags

Comment: What is your version of SQL Server?

Comment: @forpas sql server 2016

Comment: @forpas Sorry its sql server 2017, do u have something which is supported in new version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @ContentTag table
(
Id int identity,
ContentId int,
TagId int
);
insert into @ContentTag(ContentId, TagId)
values
(48, 3), (48, 4), (48, 5), (48, 6),
(47, 7), (47, 8), (47, 1), (47, 2), 
(46, 4), (46, 6);

declare @FolderTag table
(
Id int identity,
FolderId int,
TagId int
);

insert into @FolderTag(FolderId, TagId)
values
(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6),
(4, 3), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (10, 1),
(11, 4), (11, 6);

select f.FolderId, c.ContentId
from 
(
    select FolderId, TagId, count(*) over(partition by FolderId) as FolderTagCount
    from @FolderTag
) as f
join
(
    select ContentId , TagId, count(*) over(partition by ContentId) as ContentTagCount
    from @ContentTag
) as c on f.TagId = c.TagId and f.FolderTagCount = c.ContentTagCount
group by f.FolderId, c.ContentId
having count(f.TagId) = max(c.ContentTagCount);
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2017 you can use [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
WITH 
  c AS (
    SELECT ContentId, STRING_AGG(TagId, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TagId) tags
    FROM ContentTag
    GROUP BY ContentId
  ),
  f AS (
    SELECT FolderId, STRING_AGG(TagId, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TagId) tags
    FROM FolderTag
    GROUP BY FolderId
  )  
SELECT c.ContentId, f.FolderId
FROM c INNER JOIN f
ON f.tags = c.tags
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1fefb190e0e8739dd56d852b708b0fb7).
Results:

```
> ContentId | FolderId
> --------: | -------:
>        48 |        2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a result with the folder and all content that has at least one matching tag, then `join` should suffice:

```
select ft.folderid, ct.contentid
from foldertags ft join
     contenttag ct
     on ft.tagid = ct.tagid
```

Comment: but it will give all the data its simple join I need to filter this result so that it contains only those contentid which are linked to exactly the same tags as folder is linked to the tags. I will try to elaborate my problem a bit more